# Will Random Forest be hurt if feature dependence within each group are disrupted?

Tags: random-forest, simulation

I am trying to create the dataset through simulation based on known empirical features of each groups (actual training data is not available) and build a RF classifier using these simulated data. The major features is known. However, I can't simulate the feature dependence within each group (say, some of the feature in certain group may show exclusive or co-occurrent pattern). Would the lost of this feature dependence compromise the performance of RF?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you want to apply Random Forest to forecast simulated data. I don't know what the reason behind this is, but I struggle to see a valid reason to do so other than testing the algorithm.

However, since the data is simulated, RF can only recognize patterns that you create when generating it. Therefore if you generate some features completely independently from your target variable, these will only be noise to the Random Forest.

In short, yes, if you ignore some correlations when creating the data, these cannot be picked up by the algorithm, which will therefore have a worse performance.

Comment: The reason I am doing it is because that the training data (raw data) is not available. All I have is several publications that classified these data into groups and described the major differences of each group

Comment: The thing is - Random Forest (or any machine learning algorithm) cannot extract information from data if the information is not there. When you're generating the data based on those descriptions, you're inserting some information in it by creating some model (correlations, dependencies etc.). The simulation procedure will add nothing else than noise, so you cannot end up with more information than you started with... Your ML model will tell you exactly what are the interactions that YOU set up when generating the data, maybe even less, or worse it will overfit, so no info is added :)